# error while build Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android

```
package comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn;

public class SharedPreferences {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyLoginPrefsFile";

}
```

```java
package comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import static comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn.SharedPreferences.PREFS_NAME;


public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout guestlogin = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.guest);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        guestlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn.SharedPreferences.PREFS_NAME, 0); // 0 - for private mode
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                //Set "hasLoggedIn" to true
                editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);

                // Commit the edits!
                editor.commit();
                Intent i = new Intent(login.this, ChoiceSelection.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

```java
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn.SharedPreferences.PREFS_NAME, 0);
//Get "hasLoggedIn" value. If the value doesn't exist yet false is returned
        boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

        if(hasLoggedIn)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, login.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
            this.finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent n = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ChoiceSelection.class);
            this.startActivity(n);
            this.finish();
        }


    }
}
```

This, I  code in javafile and then this error show me while debug.I delete this files also and set file to previously, but I did not get any solution. My build.gradle and main.xml is also right and there is error showing while gradle sync only in debuging.I try Restart and Invalides Caches

Comment: What is this error? How was it generated? Where was the error generated? Please share some code and information about the issue so that we can help you

Comment: @Kartik I was due to Building SharedManager file and login file

Comment: package comviewappisome.google.sites.watchandearn;

public class SharedPreferences {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyLoginPrefsFile";

}

Comment: Hi please share the code and the issue and edit the question. Do not explain the issue in comments :)

Comment: @Kartik Done Check now

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with Preferences at all. There is something else that is throwing this error.

Comment: @Kartik what i will send you

Answer (score 0):

Your client expects an array (or JSON array) but it gets an string (starts with '"') . check your string and find out the difference between. maybe it needs to remove quotation marks from start and end. but to be honest, you must LOG them to get a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is caused by other classes. If you are using a web service, the json format returned from there is the wrong format.

Comment: but i did not  use any web service or any server work

Comment: Search for "JSONObject" in your project and try to find something. If you do not reach such a result, there is a problem in one of the libraries you have used recently.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by cleaning the build!